# retrieve an object from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve an object called `keywords` from an ArrayList based on list of `terms`.

I wrote a code to retrieve the index of the object and copy it to another ArrayList `Ar2`

```
    public ArrayList GetGrams(int n, ArrayList Keywords) {
    ArrayList Ar = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList Ar2 = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
        if (Keywords.toString().contains(terms.get(i).toString())) 
        {
            String myString = terms.get(i).toString();;
            int myIndex=0;
            myIndex = Keywords.toString().indexOf(myString,0);

            Ar.add(terms.get(i));
            Ar2.add(Keywords.get(myIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

the problem the index that I have incorrect which is 1181 while the keywords contain only 150 keywords.

In summary: I need to copy the corresponding object in `keywords` to Ar2 that match the `terms`.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using generics? Also, it would be easier to read your code if you'd pay more attention to indentation and follow Java naming conventions. Additionally, it's not at all clear why you're calling `toString()` so much. I strongly suspect you shouldn't be calling `toString` *at all*. And what's the point of the `n` parameter? I'm basically very confused as to what this is trying to do at all. It would really help if you could give sample input and desired output.

Comment: this is part of the program. So, each object in `Keywords` contain some attributes such as: words, weight, and support. that I need to use it later on the program. So I need to compare the terms from the `terms` Arraylist and copy the corresponding keywords which is the `word` in the object, for that I use `toString()` to compare.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer any of my questions... and if you need to compare specific parts in `Keywords`, why don't you fetch that specific property? Your question is too unclear to answer at the moment.

Comment: The inclusion of generics on your array lists, and their associated class definitions would be immensely helpful. I'm assuming that you have overridden `toString()` to somehow fit your needs, but even if you have, accessing the objects' members for equality comparison would be a far better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You use index to find position of word in the string but `ArrayList` has own index.
This is not correct: `Keywords.get(myIndex))` where `myIndex` will be definitely more than `ArrayList` size.
Then you should not convert `ArrayList` to `String`, just use `keywords.contains(object)`.

Comment: I tried `keywords.contains(object)`, but it is a boolean and return True and False only.

Comment: if (keywords.contains(terms.get(i))) {Ar.add(terms.get(i));           Ar2.add(terms.get(i));} - if terms.get(i) exists in keywords, add this word to both array as you need. You don't need myIndex at all. But I don't know why you need 2 arrays.